# Splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in whole word

Tags: java, regex, string

i have a string like:

```
String test = "firstName:a,lastName:b,addressOne:line 1,line 2,city:other";
```

i am trying to do `test.replaceAll(",","\",\"")`.I mean replace , with ",". I want to this only for the whole strings. For eg addressOne is a single string with comma seperated i dont want to replace that. Is there any regex or someother way i can do this?
i should get a string like

```
"firstName":"a","lastName":"b","addressOne":"line 1 , line 2","city":"other"
after replace , but i am getting 
"firstName":"a","lastName":"b","addressOne":"line 1 "," line 2","city":"other".
```

Comment: Is that even a valid Java statement?

Comment: donno what u r expecting.. string or list or burger ?

Comment: The first line makes no sense. Please rewrite. Also, is this JSON?

Comment: We understand the concept, it is just that you haven't taken the ball far enough down the field. Not responded to any questions. We would probably expect the latter, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your string with commas that are followed by a word which has been followed by `:`. And for this aim you can use a [positive look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and for matching the leading word use a negated character class `[^:,]+` which will match any string except `:` and `,`:

```
test.split(",(?=[^:,]+:)")
```